# Visual Studio 2022 Exclude Transitive Package from Build

Tags: .net, visual-studio, aws-lambda, build, nuget

I have a C# AWS Lambda function that's just breached the 50MB limit on uploading to AWS.

The culprit for the zip file being so large is a trio of files (libz3.dll, libz3.so and Microsoft.Z3.dll) related to the Microsoft Z3 solver. Now, I'm not using Z3 and if I remove these files from the zip file it reduces its size by 40% and everything works fine.

You can see here that Microsoft.Z3 is a 'sub-dependency' of Optano.Modelling. It shows up as a transitive package in NuGet manager. I wonder if this is mistake in the Optano.Modelling NuGet package that causes it to be included, considering I have to add the Gurobi solver as a separate NuGet package (which you can also see here).

[image]

It's getting really rather tiresome having to remove these files from the zip file and manually upload it from AWS Console every time I need to update it following a code change (which is frequent at the moment).

So, my question is, how I can prevent it from including these three files, or perhaps ignoring the Z3 package, when building and publishing the Lambda function?

Edit: I've now tried quite a lot of things, including numerous variations on Bowman Zhu-MSFT's answer, but nothing works.

Comment: You can use msbuild task to delete the files when build target. See my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just give an example of remove the file via msbuild:

**.csproj file:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="OPTANO.Modeling" Version="3.15.0.580" />
  </ItemGroup>


    <Target Name="DeleteFile">
        <Delete Files="bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Microsoft.Z3.dll" >
        </Delete>
        <Delete Files="bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\libz3.dll" >
        </Delete>
        <Delete Files="bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\libz3.so" >
        </Delete>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

The above path is just a sample, if the path that your package step use is another, just change the path before the dll file name.

`msbuild -t:DeleteFile`

Then you will find those files not in target path:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How do I make that target run when publishing? Do I have to run msbuild from the command line in order to add that flag? If so that doesn't help as it only saves the step of deleting those three files, which is the least annoying step out of all the faff involved in manually publishing the Lambda function without those files in it.

Comment: I've tried overriding predefined targets according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/msbuild/how-to-extend-the-visual-studio-build-process?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN) but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's a somewhat dirty-feeling workaround, but I edited the 'Microsoft.Z3.targets' file in the downloaded NuGet package itself, and changed the 'CopyToOutputDirectory' parameter for 'libz3.dll' to 'Never'.

I still don't know how to make it exclude 'libz3.dll' and 'Microsoft.Z3.dll' but at least the zip file is now down to 44.4 MB and therefore below the limit so I can publish the function normally.

It would still be better if I could exclude those two other files because they represent 15 MB of extraneous data that needs to brought in every time the Lambda function is instantiated.